# how to test controllers with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

please give any link for tutorial for controllers testing with rspec, how to start I am not able to do, I am the beginner in testing,
here is the code of controller:

```
  def login
    if admin_logged_in?
      flash[:notice]="You are already logged in"
      redirect_to( "/admin/")
    else
      render(:layout => "admin")
    end
  end
```

how to test for this method.

Comment: you can start from this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec/

Answer (score 0):

check this two links:
a Style Guide on testing https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#controllers-1
and this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/71-testing-controllers-with-rspec